# Is .NET AesManaged cryptography hardware accelerated?

Tags: .net, aes, hardware-acceleration

Does anyone know whether the AesManaged Cryptography provider from .NET (>4.0) supports hardware acceleration, if the CPU has AES extensions (Like Haswell based CPU)?

If so, is there a way to confirm with code?

Comment: Asking for third-party libraries is considered [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I deleted the last paragraph from your question to save it from being closed.

Comment: The *managed* implementation is certainly not accelerated. The cryptoserviceprovider implementation could in theory be accelerated, but the performance is so bad this is highly unlikely.

Comment: I'd consider using a wrapper over a third party native library. I think OpenSSL supports accelerated AES.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Thanks. Do you any official reference confirming that?

Comment: @DCastro - Understood, though I don't agree, given we already have a comment making mention of a 3rd party lib, so clearly not so off-topic after all.

Comment: Next time reword it: "Is there any way of letting `AesManaged` Cryptography provider use AES extensions in the CPU?" If that method requires a library, then so be it :)

Comment: Why is AesManaged clearly not hw accelerated? I assume that it is up to JIT to decide which instructions will be used, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly the .NET `AesManaged` implementation is not hardware accelerated. Searches of SO and Google indicate that `AesCryptoServiceProvider` (which is a wrapper over the OS crypto) is generally much slower than the `AesManaged` implementation.

However, I have found that the `AesCryptoServiceProvider` was actually faster, way faster, as in order of magnitude difference. I'm suspecting that the OS level implementation is actually handing AES-NI instructions off to the CPU for hardware acceleration.

I cannot locate any documentation on the above observation, but if my suspicions are correct then at least on a Core i7 4770 CPU running 64-Bit Windows 8.1 Update 1, the `AesCryptoServiceProvider` is hardware accelerated.

Performance observations are that on the above machine, 8 threads of AES CBC decryption using `AesManaged` will max out the CPU and consume as much memory as needed for the data (i.e. for us 32GB of RAM gets maxed out regularly). The exact same code but using `AesCryptoServiceProvider` has the CPU cores average around 30-40% and memory (private working bytes) seldom go over 10GB.

To semi-answer my own question, try `AesCryptoServiceProvider`, especially on 64-bit Windows 8.1 Update 1.

Comment: `CryptoServiceProvider` are generally slow on short inputs since they have a large per-call overhead. For long messages they're generally faster than the managed variants. But don't ask me why the overhead is large - it can't just be p/invoke overhead since calling other native libs is much faster.